# Greenplum : Is there a way to define a table that data will be stored in master only

Tags: greenplum

**In Greenplum data base**, Is there a way to define a table that data will be stored in master only ?

Answer (score 1):

No, such tables are not supported in Greenplum. Also Greenplum does not support "replicated" table that stores the same data on all the segments. If you will clarify your case I would recommend you solution. Storing data on the master is not a good choice because in most cases no data processing is done on master

Answer (score 1):

Got one solution

Follow below steps:

a>     Create a table without any column

```
create table test_monly();
```

b>    Then alter table and add some column

```
alter table test_monly add column x integer;
```

c>     Now  insert some records

```
insert into test_monly values(1);
insert into test_monly values(3);
insert into test_monly values(5);
insert into test_monly values(7);
```

d>    Check using this query

```
select gp_segment_id,x from test_monly
```

e>    All the records are available in master only

Comment: GP master doesn't store data except some system tables.   Here is the citation from GP Install Guide, Chapter 1: Introduction to Greenplum section "The Greenplum Master" The master maintains the system catalog (a set of system tables that contain metadata about the Greenplum Database system itself), however the master does not contain any user data. Data resides only on the segments

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify the distributed by clause, your table will only stored in one segment. But it is not guaranteed that the table will be stored in the master.

Comment: my above solution, stored data in master only

Comment: GP master doesn't store data except some system tables.                                   
Here is the words cited from GP Install Guide, Chapter 1: Introduction to Greenplum section "The Greenplum Master"

The master maintains the system catalog (a set of system tables that contain metadata about the Greenplum Database system itself), however the master does not contain any user data. Data resides only on the segments